# An internal OpenGL call failed in Texture.cpp(98) Vector of sfml windows

Tags: c++, sfml

So I have A sfml program and I am trying to have multiple windows open at once. I know I had a functioning code but I couldn't have more than one main loop running at a time. I have made a vector of pointers to windows and a vector of a structure I made. Inside the function I'm trying to use to replace the while loop that would be running in each open window I have a for loop inside the function that should run through whole vector and render everything. I've narrowed down the code generating the error to either the stepWindows function or my function that adds a new window. I have no idea what I did wrong but there are no compiler errors however, the debug console is having a error:

```cpp
An internal OpenGL call failed in Texture.cpp(98).
Expression:
   glFlush()
Error description:
   GL_INVALID_OPERATION
   The specified operation is not allowed in the current state.
```

Here is my StepWindows Function I made it inside the class MakeKey

```cpp
void MakeKey::StepWindows(vector <MakeKey::NewKey> KeyArray, vector <sf::RenderWindow*> WindowArray)
{
    for (int i{ 0 }; i > KeyArray.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Inside Step Windows For Loop" << endl;
        WindowArray[1]->setActive(true);
        WindowArray[1]->clear(sf::Color::Transparent);
        WindowArray[1]->draw(KeyArray[1].Sprite);
        WindowArray[1]->display();
    }
}
```

Here is the section that makes a new window

```cpp
void MakeKey::DrawKey(string input, vector <MakeKey::NewKey>* KeyArray, vector <sf::RenderWindow*>* WindowArray)
{
    MakeKey::NewKey Key;
    if (input == "A")
        Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/A.png");
    else if (input == "D")
        Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/D.png");
    //Ect
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(Key.Img.getSize().x, Key.Img.getSize().y, 32), "Key", sf::Style::None);
    Key.Tex.loadFromImage(Key.Img);
    Key.Sprite.setTexture(Key.Tex);
    sf::RenderWindow* windowPoint = &window;
    //Make Transparent
    const unsigned char opacity = 1000;
    KeyArray->push_back(Key);
    WindowArray->push_back(&window);
    cout << "KeyArray Has " << KeyArray->size() << " Elements\n" << "WindowArray Has " << WindowArray->size() << " Elements" << endl; //for debugging
}
```

And of course my main

```cpp
int main()
{
    static vector <MakeKey::NewKey> KeyArray;
    static vector <MakeKey::NewKey>* KeyArrayPointer = &KeyArray;
    static vector <sf::RenderWindow*> WindowArray;
    static vector <sf::RenderWindow*>* WindowArrayPointer = &WindowArray;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(100, 100, 32), "Main Window", sf::Style::Default);
    MakeKey MakeKey;
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            //Key Presses
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A)
                    MakeKey.DrawKey("A", KeyArrayPointer, WindowArrayPointer);
                else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::D)
                    MakeKey.DrawKey("D", KeyArrayPointer, WindowArrayPointer);
                //Ect
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        MakeKey.StepWindows(KeyArray, WindowArray);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Thanks guys

Comment: An internal OpenGL call failed in Texture.cpp(98). <<< it would be good to post the code around this line.

Comment: That is part of the sfml library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DrawKey method, you appear to be creating a new window each time you press a key *(as a temporary, which will be destroyed at the point DrawKey returns)*

```cpp
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(Key.Img.getSize().x, Key.Img.getSize().y, 32), "Key", sf::Style::None);
```

You then take the address of that temporary, and store it's address.

```cpp
    WindowArray->push_back(&window);
```

which means WindowArray now holds a pointer to a dead object. Something about the whole set up looks very fishy to me.

I'm no expert on sfml, but I'd have assumed that if you needed to have multiple windows open, this would be the way to do it:

```cpp
// just store the windows in a normal array
static std::vector<sf::RenderWindow> windows;

// add main window (and do this if you need to add more windows)
windows.emplace_back(sf::VideoMode(100, 100, 32), "Main Window", sf::Style::Default);

// keep the app running while a window is open.
while(!windows.empty())
{
  for(auto window = windows.begin(); window != windows.end(); ++window)
  {
    if(!window->isOpen())
    {
      // if main window closed, clear all windows (and exit main loop)
      if(window == windows.begin())
      {
        windows.clear();
      }
      else
      {
        // erase the window that was closed
        window = windows.erase(window);
      }
    }
    else
    // process all queued events for window
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window->pollEvent(event))
        {
          //Key Presses
          if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
             if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A)
                MakeKey.DrawKey("A", KeyArray, windows);
             else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::D)
                MakeKey.DrawKey("D", KeyArray, windows);
             //Ect
          }
          if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
          {
             window->close();
             break;
          }
        }
    }
    MakeKey.StepWindows(KeyArray, windows);
  }
}
```

This would imply a few changes to your drawkey function (I'm assuming the intention is to create a new window each time a key is pressed??). You would probably find it easier to pass references to the vectors, instead of pointers to the vectors.

```
void MakeKey::DrawKey(
  std::string input, 
  std::vector<MakeKey::NewKey>& KeyArray,  //< pass by reference
  std::vector<sf::RenderWindow>& WindowArray) //< pass by reference
{
    MakeKey::NewKey Key;
    if (input == "A")
        Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/A.png");
    else if (input == "D")
        Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/D.png");
    //Ect|

    /// << add the window to the array >>
    WindowArray.emplace_back(sf::VideoMode(Key.Img.getSize().x, Key.Img.getSize().y, 32), "Key", sf::Style::None);

    Key.Tex.loadFromImage(Key.Img);
    Key.Sprite.setTexture(Key.Tex);
    //Make Transparent
    const unsigned char opacity = 1000;
    KeyArray.push_back(Key);
    std::cout << "KeyArray Has " << KeyArray.size() << " Elements\n" << "WindowArray Has " << WindowArray.size() << " Elements" << std::endl; //for debugging
}
```

Your step windows function is a little confusing, so I assume you are trying to do something like this?

```cpp
void MakeKey::StepWindows(const std::vector <MakeKey::NewKey>& KeyArray, std::vector <sf::RenderWindow>& WindowArray)
{
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < KeyArray.size(); i++)     {
        cout << "Inside Step Windows For Loop" << endl;

        // are you sure you only want to do this for window 1? 
        // It would sort of make sense to do this for window[i + 1]??
        // but you will need to ensure that when you erase a window above,
        // you also erase the corresponding element from the key array???
        WindowArray[1 + i]->setActive(true);
        WindowArray[1 + i]->clear(sf::Color::Transparent);
        WindowArray[1 + i]->draw(KeyArray[1].Sprite);
        WindowArray[1 + i]->display();
    }
}
```

Comment: This specifically will not work but thank you for showing me where the error was and what I should clean up. It specifically won't work because emplace_back uses copy method and render windows are noncopyable. That is why I was trying to use pointers. Knowing that how should I go about pushing back the values?